# Create Dynamic Route in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, dynamic-routing

I have set up my Gatsby Project.

I know how to create a Route, by defining the Component in "page".
Now I want to create a dynamic Route, so I can pass my channelId.
In React I can do `<Route path="/channel/:channelId/details"/>`.
Is there a similar way in Gatsby?

Edited:

I read under: [Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/#creating-client-only-routes), that I can set a path like this: "/src/pages/channel/[channelId]/details.tsx" and then a url like "/channel/13/details" should work. I would prefer this method to the "gatsby-node.js" method.
I get my channels from a self made API.
My filestrukture looks like this:

```
frontend
  -src
    -components
      -layout
        -layout.tsx
    -pages
      -index.tsx
      -channel
        -[channelId]
          -details.tsx
```

Now when I open "/channel/13/details" I get this error: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfkY8.png)

My gatsby-config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'NewsHub',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'News-Hub',
        short_name: 'NewsHub',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#f7f0eb',
        theme_color: '#38A8CB',
        display: 'standalone',
        icon: 'src/images/logo-blue.png',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/src/images/'),
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-typescript-css-modules',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. Having a `gatsby-node.js` like:

```
const path = require("path")
  
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                path
                channelId
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  const channelTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/channel.js`)

  // Create pages for each markdown file.

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const channelId = node.frontmatter.channelId;

    createPage({
      path: `/channel/${channelId}/details`,
      component: channelTemplate,
      context: {
        channelId,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: modified from https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/*

I'm assuming a markdown-based source but the idea is exactly the same given any source (JSON, YAML, CMS, etc). Gatsby creates dynamic pages given any source, in that case, I'm looping through local markdowns files to get the `channelId` and pass it to the template through context.

Each page will have a dynamic path like path: `/channel/${channelId}/details`.

Once in the view, you can use this `channelId` to create a specific query to get the details from that channel or use it directly with `props.pageContext.channelId`

Comment: I dont get my Channels with any GraphQL queries. So I think no channelId's are in any markdown files.
I read somewhere, that I can just do it, when making a path like this: "/src/pages/channel/[channelId]/details.tsx". When I do this and call "/channel/13/details", then I get this: 
`Gatsby.js development 404 page
Pages: /channel/[channelId]/details`

Comment: Well, in that case, share as many details of your integration and what's "somewhere else" and if you are using system route API, share your folder structure.

Comment: I edited my Question with more details

Comment: Thanks for the details! It's interesting because it's not generating nor catching the `[channelId]` route. Have you tried using splat routes ( `[...].js`) just to check if the ID is present somehow but wrong nested?

Comment: Yes I also tried that, this gives me the same error.